# How to detect a string's hash algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, hash, detect

How to detect a string's hash algorithm?
Does each hash algorithms create a unique characteristic?

Comment: You can often guess based on the number of bits involved, but there are infinitely many functions that can generate a given hash.  (If the set of possible functions is restricted to the popular algorithms, then you can usually narrow it down to 1 or 2.  For example, a 32 character hex string, or 128 bit binary blob is almost always an md5 hash.)

Answer (score 4):

All cryptographically strong hashes of a given bitlength (or equivalently, a hash with a longer bitlength that's been truncated) are indistinguishable by examining their outputs - because, in order to be a secure hash function, they have to produce evenly distributed outputs; any variation in their output would be an exploitable weakness.